# Release build - resultset does not return result but debug version works

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2010

I currently have the following code which works fine in my debug build

```
        std::vector<std::string> DB::ReturnResult()
        {
            std::vector<std::string> SymbolList;
            std::string SQL = "SELECT ....";
            prep_stmt = con->prepareStatement(SQL);
            res = prep_stmt->executeQuery();
            while(res->next()) 
            {   
                SymbolList.push_back(res->getString("Column"));
            }
            return SymbolList;
        }
```

This code works fine in the debug build but the release version does not return any result from the tables.Any suggestions ? I am using VS2010 C++

Comment: The code you are showing here looks correct (and I very much doubt you have found a compiler bug in something this trivial, but I have been wrong on those things before. Are you able to produce a reproducable result in a small, complete example?

Comment: I believe I can. Any chance the the runtime library should be different from the debug library. I currently use mysqlcppconn-static.lib and mysqlcppconn.lib for both debug and release dependencies